# Oracle, defining variables in a WITH query

Tags: oracle

Just wondering if it is possible to define variables in a WITH query? I've tried but query keeps failing.

Just something like

```
WITH

DEFINE var1 = 'ABC';

SUBQUERY1 (col1, col2)
AS
(SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE COL1 = &var1)

SELECT * FROM subquery1

;
```

Thanks in advance

K

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on **exactly** what it is you want to do, but you could also do something like this (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=50d2c63a0f1bcb0c1c48644ba3570fb5)):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1 VARCHAR (50), col2 INT);
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('ABC', 1); 
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('DEF', 2);
```

and then run the following query:

```
WITH cte1 (x, y) AS
(
  SELECT col1, col2 
  FROM table1 WHERE col1 = (SELECT 'ABC' FROM dual)
)  
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

Result:

```
  X  Y
ABC  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `WITH` in your example? That said, in SQL*Plus the `DEFINE` must be separate from the query:

```
DEFINE var1 = 'ABC';
WITH SUBQUERY1 (col1, col2) AS
     (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE COL1 = &var1)
SELECT * FROM subquery1;
```

A better way to do this specific example would be not to use `WITH` at all:

```
DEFINE var1 = 'ABC';
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 WHERE COL1 = &var1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A WITH clause can only contain SQL or PL/SQL, not `DEFINE`, because queries are sent to the server for execution.

You could define a function for each parameter you needed, for example:

```
with function param1 return varchar2 as
     begin
         return 'X';
     end;
select * from dual d
where  d.dummy = param1
```